# how to download .apk files from one Android app on button click?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've an Android App where there is a Button which allows to download `.apk` file from the web server. There is a website hosted on the web and .apk files are uploaded to this website, say the website is `http://xxx` and .apk files are stored inside a folder say, `Games/Apk/demo.apk`. Now I want to download this `.apk` file from my App say `MYAPP1`, there is a button and onclick I want to download the .apk file from the server to my device SD Card
How can I do this?
`I tried giving http://xxx/Games/Apk/myApp.apk` but it doesn't work.
Can you people please tell me how to download .apk file.

what else I've to do on my website and in my app?
Thank you in advance... :)

Comment: You tried giving the URL to what?

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar Here is what exactly I'm doing right now is [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087229/unable-to-download-apk-file-from-remote-server-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1.**
Try to embedd a Browser into the link and download it from the server directly. That is a clean way to accomplish this.

```
    WebView  webView = ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview));
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); //plugins/flash
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

**Method 2.**
You can also have a get request to serve this apk file and then your buton on click can send the file in a AsyncTask. There are many examples of doing this on the internet.

2.1 **Storing on SD card**

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

2.2 **Writing to file**

```
    FileOutputStream fop = openFileOutput(“my_file”, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
fop.write(“Data to be written”.getBytes());
fop.flush();
fop.close();
```

2.3 **Async Task Http Request**

[Android HTTP Request AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829135/android-http-request-asynctask)

Comment: Method 1. Try to embedd a Browser into the app and download it from the server directly. That is a clean way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

We can  embedd a Browser into application which can download it from the server ...
suppose we have webcontent.xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

suppose our webactivity is as follows

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webcontent);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.apkdwonloadlink.com");


    }

}
```

we can callit from Mainactivity as follows

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }

        });
    }
}
```

please add permissions on manifest for internet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```