# How to Use Download manager to download an apk from a website and then show prompt to install it?

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I want my app to download an apk file from a website through download manager when a button is clicked and want to show the prompt to install when the download is finished. Is it possible to do that? If yes, then how?

Currently I'm using

```
downloades = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloades);
downloades.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=<package_name>"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

to open the app in Google Play for the user to download it. But I want to download the APK file from a website (for an instance Mediafire) and prompt the user to install the app. Any solutions for it?

Comment: A similar question has already been posted to download an apk, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21129649/7828834