# How to fix error on trying to download an app programatically from a random website with proper android manifest permissions.?

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

Im trying to download an app from a random website (not my server or owned by me) and store it in a specific location in the device storage. Then I would show a prompt to the user to install the app. I have included these permissions in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

But Im not able to download the app from the website. The logcat shows

```
04-01 11:48:08.774 8860-9036/com.joy.skylake.testapplication E/MainActivity: Update Error: https://www.apkfollow.com/download/arb_com.yirgalab.dzzz_2016-06-03.apk/
```

**Here's the code.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
ProgressDialog bar;
private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
private int AppVersion = 1;

protected boolean shouldAskPermissions() {
    return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
}

@TargetApi(23)
protected void askPermissions() {
    String[] permissions = {
            "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
            "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    };
    int requestCode = 200;
    requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (shouldAskPermissions()) {
        askPermissions();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading);

    heading.setText("App Version: " + AppVersion);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dwnload);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            new DownloadNewVersion().execute();



        }
    });
}

class DownloadNewVersion extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        bar = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        bar.setCancelable(false);

        bar.setMessage("Downloading...");

        bar.setIndeterminate(true);
        bar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        bar.show();

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

        bar.setIndeterminate(false);
        bar.setMax(100);
        bar.setProgress(progress[0]);
        String msg = "";
        if(progress[0]>99){

            msg="Finishing... ";

        }else {

            msg="Downloading... "+progress[0]+"%";
        }
        bar.setMessage(msg);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        bar.dismiss();

        if(result){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Installed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        Boolean flag = false;

        try {


            URL url = new URL("https://www.apkfollow.com/download/arb_com.yirgalab.dzzz_2016-06-03.apk/");

            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();


            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/";
            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();

            File outputFile = new File(file,"arb_com.yirgalab.dzzz_2016-06-03.apk");

            if(outputFile.exists()){
                outputFile.delete();
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            int total_size = 3045565;//size of apk

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            int per = 0;
            int downloaded=0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                downloaded +=len1;
                per = (int) (downloaded * 100 / total_size);
                publishProgress(per);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();

            OpenNewVersion(PATH);

            flag = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Update Error: " + e.getMessage());
            flag = false;
        }
        return flag;

    }

}

void OpenNewVersion(String location) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(location + "arb_com.yirgalab.dzzz_2016-06-03.apk")),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

As I found this code [here](http://androidpala.com/install-android-app-programmatically/) while searching for a solution to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49591966/how-to-use-download-manager-to-download-an-apk-from-a-website-and-then-show-prom) Im not understanding what could be the cause of it. Any help?

Comment: Is 'Allow installation of non-Market-applications or unknown' sources switched on in your device settings ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It was due to website issue. I uploaded the file on Dropbox and tried replacing the url with Dropbox direct download link and everything worked as expected. Thanks everyone